AC is not working
My wall HVAC thermostat was loose on wall, so I made it tighter, but it was reported by my tenant that heater is working but AC is not working (not even kicking off). The AC breaker is on.
One thing I found in the attached picture which was taken before I make it tight: there was U pin running between R and RC, which is now missing after I reinstalled.
Is that U pin or jumper wire missing not to kick off the AC?  I think I  have lost it :(. where to get that from?
Please advise.



NOTE: This is only for low voltage thermostats.
In ye olden times, a standard paper clip (not the jumbo size - those were too thick) was the usual tool for troubleshooting low-voltage communications, particularly RS-2323C and similar serial ports. I know at least one time I found this officially documented in a printer manual. 12V, low current, low speed. Not that much different from a typical low voltage thermostat. Some examples:
Paper Clip Loopback Test
Paper Clip Test
How can I make sure my serial port is working in Windows?
and specifically for thermostats:
How to Use a Jump to Test a Thermostat includes:

The low voltage at a thermostat isn't hazardous, so you could even use a paper clip.

A paper clip should work fine in general as a thermostat jumper, though the official part from the manufacturer would probably cost more than an entire box of paper clips.
Personally, I would have no problem trying that on a low-voltage thermostat such as in your picture. But don't ever use a paper clip (or anything other than properly insulated copper wire) on a line voltage (120V or 240V) thermostat. That would be, literally, playing with fire.

Fortunately I found the jumper clip on carpet. I installed and it started working. Thank you!
